# How can i do this using linq in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of schedule objects in c# contains following entries:

EDIT: Edited to copy/pasteable data

Classes:

```
    public class Trade
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String StartDate { get; set; }
        public String EndDate { get; set; }
        public Time[] Times { get; set; }
    }

    public class Time
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Start { get; set; }
        public int End { get; set; }
    }
```

Array:

```
[TestFixture]
public class LinqTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var trades = new Trade[]
        {
            new Trade
            {
                Id = 1,
                StartDate = "01/01/2014",
                EndDate = "01/01/2014",
                Times = new[] {new Time {Id = 1, Start = 60, End = 120}, new Time {Id = 2, Start = 180, End = 240}}
            },
            new Trade
            {
                Id = 2,
                StartDate = "02/01/2014",
                EndDate = "02/01/2014",
                Times = new[] {new Time {Id = 1, Start = 60, End = 120}, new Time {Id = 2, Start = 180, End = 240}}
            },
            new Trade
            {
                Id = 3,
                StartDate = "03/01/2014",
                EndDate = "03/01/2014",
                Times = new[] {new Time {Id = 1, Start = 60, End = 120}, new Time {Id = 2, Start = 180, End = 240}}
            },
            new Trade
            {
                Id = 4,
                StartDate = "04/01/2014",
                EndDate = "04/01/2014",
                Times = new[] {new Time {Id = 1, Start = 60, End = 120}}
            },
            new Trade
            {
                Id = 5,
                StartDate = "05/01/2014",
                EndDate = "05/01/2014",
                Times = new[] {new Time {Id = 1, Start = 160, End = 220}, new Time {Id = 2, Start = 380, End = 840}}
            },
            new Trade
            {
                Id = 6,
                StartDate = "06/01/2014",
                EndDate = "06/01/2014",
                Times = new[] {new Time {Id = 1, Start = 160, End = 220}, new Time {Id = 2, Start = 380, End = 840}}
            }
        };
    }
```

I want to merge the entries whose StartDate is in sequence and Times entries Start and End are same. So the output should be :

```
[ 
 { 
   Id = 1, 
   StartDate = "01/01/2014", 
   EndDate = "03/01/2014" 
   Times = [{ Id = 1 Start = 60, End = 120 }, { Id = 2 Start = 180, End = 240 }]
 },
 { 
   Id = 4, 
   StartDate = "04/01/2014", 
   EndDate = "04/01/2014" 
   Times = [{ Id = 1 Start = 60, End = 120 }]
 },
 { 
   Id = 5, 
   StartDate = "05/01/2014", 
   EndDate = "06/01/2014" 
   Times = [{ Id = 1 Start = 160, End = 220 }, { Id = 2 Start = 380, End = 840 }]
 },
]
```

How can i do this in c# (using linq if possible) ?

Comment: Why don't you show your class and how you've constructed this sample data? That would make it much more simple to test the code you want us to write for you.

Comment: `whose StartDate is in sequence` what sequence? It's totally unclear what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: GroupBy on Times for Start and End, than OrderBy StartDate

Comment: So many people clicked here wanting to help you using their linq-fu, but can't because you haven't provided some starting code.

Comment: Just edited it, so we can all have a play with it, this is from my assumption of his array

Comment: @MichalCiechan: Please move your answer to an actual answer instead of editing it into the question.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Have Done, couldn't post answer as it was marked of topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom comparer for the times array.:

```
    public class TimeArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<Time[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(Time[] x, Time[] y)
        {
            if (x == y) return true;
            if (x == null) return false;
            return GetHashCode(x) == GetHashCode(y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Time[] obj)
        {
            if(obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
            return obj.Aggregate(-1, (current, time) => current ^ (time.Start.GetHashCode() ^ time.End.GetHashCode()));
        }
    }
```

And then GroupBy Times, and select first item in group, setting the EndDate with the last item in group:

```
        var groups = trades.GroupBy(trade => trade.Times, new TimeArrayComparer());

        var result = groups.Select(grouping =>
        {
            var trade = grouping.First();
            trade.EndDate = grouping.Last().EndDate;
            return trade;
        });
```

But you should implement a better comparer than that! THat is for demonstration only!